# How to implement bidirectional relationship in Spring Spanner?

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In code, I tried with @Interleaved in 1-many relationship at non-owning side to get child list. Could anyone help with below questions:

1. How to implement bidirectional relationship e.g. get parent from child for 1-1, 1-many relationship
2. Regarding many-many relationship, what are best practices to implement it and how to implement bidirectional relationship for it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Spanner currently doesn't offer a way to enforce foreign-key constraints between non-interleaved tables. You will have to enforce such constraints in your application logic. You could use [DML statements in Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-tasks#client-library-write-then-read)(that come with the ability to read-your-writes in a Cloud Spanner transaction) to enforce these constraints at insert time by inserting into your tables as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Referenced(key1,value1) VALUES ('Referenced','Value1');
INSERT INTO Referencing(key2, value2, key1) 
SELECT 'Referencing', 'Value2', key1 FROM Referenced WHERE
key1 = 'Referenced';
```

Running the two statements in a read-write transaction will ensure that the PK-FK relationship between the `Referenced` and `Referencing` table is always maintained at insert time. You may have to similarly modify update requests/SQL update statements in your application logic to enforce the PK-FK constraint for updates.

Comment: Thanks @adi for sharing information. However, what I wanted to know are: 1. how to get non-owning entity in 1-n, 1-1 relationship from owning entity like in JPA (from n side to get 1 side). 2. How to implement m-n best considering table/interleave manner.

Answer (score 2):

For a **1-many relationship**, when  using interleaved tables, then the child row's primary key *already contains* the primary key of its parent, so it is trivial to get the parent row.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    parent_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    ...
) PRIMARY KEY (parent_key);

CREATE TABLE child (
    parent_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    child_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    ...
) PRIMARY KEY (parent_key, child_key),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT parent ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If for some reason you do not have the key of the parent, and only the key of the child, then for efficiency you would need to create an index for the reverse lookup:

```
CREATE INDEX child_to_parent_index 
ON child (
    child_key
);
```

and force use of that index when performing the query for the parent:

```
SELECT 
    p.* 
FROM 
    parent as p 
JOIN 
    child@{FORCE_INDEX=child_by_id_index} AS c ON p.parent_key = c.parent_key 
WHERE 
    c.child_key = @CHILD_KEY_VALUE;
```

**Many-many relationships** would have to be implemented using a 'mapping' table linking `table1-key` to `table2-key`.
You will also need a top-level index to get efficient reverse-lookups, and use the `FORCE_INDEX` directive as above in your queries.

And as @adi mentioned, foreign key constraints would have to be enforced by the application.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    table1_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    ...
) PRIMARY KEY (table1_key);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    table2_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    ...
) PRIMARY KEY (table2_key);

CREATE TABLE table1_table2_map (
    table1_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    table2_key INT64 NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY (table1_key, table2_key);

CREATE INDEX table2_table1_map_index 
ON table1_table2_map (
    table2_key
) STORING (
    table1_key
);
```

Your application would be responsible for keeping the referential integrity of the mapping table - deleting the mapping rows when rows in `table1` or `table2` are deleted

If you want to use interleaved tables, then if your application needs to perform bi-directional lookups, you may have to create 2 mapping tables - as a child of each parent, so that finding the mappings from both directions are equally efficient.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    table1_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    ...
) PRIMARY KEY (table1_key);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    table2_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    ...
) PRIMARY KEY (table2_key);

CREATE TABLE table1_table2_map (
    table1_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    table2_key INT64 NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY (table1_key, table2_key),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT table1 ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE table2_table1_map (
    table2_key INT64 NOT NULL,
    table1_key INT64 NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY (table2_key, table1_key),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT table2 ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Note that the application needs to keep *both* of these mapping tables up to date -- ie when deleting a row from table1, the application has to get the referenced `table2_key` values and delete the mappings from the `table2_table1_map` (and vice versa).

Comment: Thanks @RedPandaCurios for long answers. Actually, I am looking for built-in function like in JPA with annotation (@ManyToOne) so that I do not have to issue a query to look up parent but it seems that Spring Spanner has not supported it yet. Anw, the other mentioned infor are good. Thanks